# Fastest Ubuntu Version?

Tags: performance, version

Oneiric is giving me a really bad performance at the moment and and I want I go back to a faster Ubuntu version. Would 10.04 give me a good performance??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its not about Ubuntu, its about the fancy stuffs that are now being shipped with Ubuntu. Then kernel per-se is pretty fast enough.

If you have used the custom version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu Ultimate UE, you can notice how worse it performs compared to the standard installation.

So, ya 10.04 would perform better than 11.10 since many fancy things like 3D graphics won't be burning your CPU cycle.

I personally think that Canonical has been declining in performance of Ubuntu steadily, 8.10 was better than 9.10, which was better than 10.10 which again was better than 11.10. But this is only a personal opinion. I have no data to back up my claim.

You can get a feel of what I said at [this page](http://tuxradar.com/content/benchmarked-ubuntu-vs-vista-vs-windows-7) which is comparing 8.10 and 9.04.

Answer (score 6):

I would say before you migrate to another version check why it is giving you bad perfomance. Is it your machine is too old? is there a long list of services/applications running on background? Once you establish that it will be easy to take a route. Here is my suggestion based on assumptions:

1. If it happens that your machine is old and cannot handle Unity 3D well then try 2D version or switch to classic gnome (I suggest 10.10).
2. If background programs/services are culprit think of disabling it and run them on demand

I would wait until you put computer specs and services running so that I can give even more solid answer!

Comment: Dual Core 2.8 Ghtz CPU, NVIDIA Geforce 8400 GS GPU, 4 GB Ram.

Comment: That shouldn't be that slow! My Presario C400 did perform well with 10.04, so I think it have something to do with software/daemons running!

Answer (score 4):

The fastest Ubuntu edition is always the server version, but if you want a GUI take a look at [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

Lubuntu is a light weight version of Ubuntu. It's made to be a faster than Ubuntu. You can download it [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/).